# Does @Transient field value get loaded?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, transient

I know @Transient field value does not get persisted in the database. But does the field value get loaded from the table when Entity is created from a query? (The field exists in the table)

```
@Transient
@Column (name = "zipcode")
Integer zipcode;
```

Comment: How can it be "loaded" if it's transient? What value could it possibly be loaded with other than null?

Comment: Its a database field.

Comment: if a field exists in the database and in the class but you only want to read from the DB then you could mark it as insertable=false, updatable=false and not as @Transient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, @Transient is to be totally ignored either in storing or loading from database

Comment: So even if the column/field exists in the table, with @Transient it gets ignored?

Comment: Correct.  Indeed, unless there is something strange going on (e.g. historical data, or something else populating it), you'd expect the database column to be empty.